# If else condition to compare 2 columns and insert a new column in Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

[image]I want to compare 2 columns using the following if else condition and update a value in the new column using some formula.

```
if df.loc[df['TF'] < df['PV']]:
    df['Par_2']] = 0.01*(1.8 * df['PV'] + 32) - 2
elif(some other condition)
```

While I execute this I get the following error

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Can any one help what can I do to resolve this error. Or is there any other way to compare 2 columns and insert a new column whose value is calculation involving some other columns as shown above.

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Comparing two vectors (columns in a dataframe) returns a vector. You can't ask if True on a vector of boolean values.

Comment: Here is the expected output. Par_2 is the newly calculated column

Comment: @ansev Have added the expected output format

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Then Can you suggest how can I insert a new column based on the condition I mentioned

Comment: please check my answer, in the `'enter here second formule'` you need put your other formule for the elif condition

Comment: @ansev Thank you. But I have total 3 conditions. I doubt if i can write all 3 in the same where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Par_2']=np.where(df['TF'] < df['PV'], 0.01*(1.8 * df['PV'] + 32) - 2,  'enter here sencond formule')
```

or [numpy.select](http://%20https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
conditions=[df['TF'] < df['PV'],df['TF'] == df['PV'],df['TF'] > df['PV']] #for example
values=[0.01*(1.8 * df['PV'] + 32) - 2, 7, 10] #for example
df['Par_2']=np.select(conditions,values)
```

Comment: Thank you @ansev. But I have total 3 condition. I doubt if i can write all 3 in the same where clause.